# hiding google ad changes Layout of application

Tags: android, android-layout

I am Facing problem while i give google ad view.GONE while no internet connection. Here is the image that is perfect when internet connection is active .
[image]

But when no internet connection previous next button go to top I think becaouse of view.GONE it losses reference.

[image]

What to do. I tried View.INVISIBLE but it occupy empty space in bottom.

I want previous next button to bottom when no internet connection.

My layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Advertisement"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/share" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/save" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Birthday Cards"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="set as Wallpaper" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Help me to solve problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` to your `LinearLayout` with the id *ll1* should work.

#### Result:

```
<!-- Other views -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Child views -->
</LinearLayout>
```

So what does *alignWithParentIfMissing* do? Let's quote the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing):

> If set to true, the parent will be used as the anchor when the anchor
>   cannot be be found for layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `RelativeLayout`, and some of your elements (LinearLayout with `id = "@+id/ll1"` for example) are placed relatively to your `AdView` ( `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` ).

Try to break this relationship or use `LinearLayout` as root layout to solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/share" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/save" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Birthday Cards"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="set as Wallpaper" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: can you change xml as your idea.No idea How to do this.

Comment: You would have to use a vertical LinearLayout as root. your header layout, viewpager, footer layout and adview would be children of your parent. to give dynamic height for your viewpager provide a height of 0 and weight of 1

Comment: Not getting please put some sample tutorial link or code link.

Answer (score 0):

Use View.GONE instead.  This will ensure it gets ignored when things get laid out.

As an aside, android:orientation is not a valid RelativeLayout attribute and will be ignored.